# How to apply 180 degrees out of phase signal at inputs of differential amplifier in laboratory when only one function generator is provided in lab?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, differential, differential-amplifier

In this differential operation experiment, two input AC signals have to be  applied to the bases such that they are 180 degrees out of phase with each other, but I am not sure how to invert an AC Signal. In DC,I had 2 power supplies and I just grounded the opposite polarity voltages together. What do I do here?

[image]

Comment: A rather long cable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a center-tapped audio transformer you can do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1B5gT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you can operate at low audio frequency range (=max. a couple of kHz), then build an inverting operational amplifier circuit which produces the inverted signal. You need an opamp, 2 identical resistors, plus and minus voltage DC power supplies and two 0,1 to 1uF capacitors for power supply decoupling.

Low frequency is a must to avoid phase shift and to allow easy construction.

A potentiometer  is useful to trim the gain to -1 accurately enough and generating the difference, if needed.

You need also a method to add some common mode noise for proper demonstration. Everything is easy with opamps when the frequency is low.

Answer (score 1):

A phase splitter can be made with a single transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxSQcI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note R5 and R6 are the (presumed) input impedances of your differential amp inputs.

The audio transformer is the cleaner solution, but might not be available.   The need for two signals is uncommon; most differential amplifiers have enough common-mode range to take a signal on (+) input and ground on (-) input.

Answer (score 1):

If your test frequency is fixed, then a PI CLC resonator gives nearly 180 degrees even if off-resonance. Use the function generator to drive the CLC thru 50 or 100 or 1,000 ohm resistor, and pick the C+L+C to resonate close to your test frequency.

Comment: Old school ....